# Mystifying redirects when serving Wordpress site on Nginx behind a Caddy reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy, caddy, caddyfile

I am self-hosting a bunch of services that are hosted in various VMs/containers and am using a Caddy v1 server as a reverse proxy to access them through various subdomains.

I recently started a couple of Wordpress sites that are hosted on a separate VM with a Nginx server and separate sites-enabled configs for each, but a shared Mariadb instance and unique WP table prefixes.

I started by hosting one of these sites on a subdomain on my main domain, let's call it apple.orange.com, and it was working fine with automatic LE certs from Caddy. I got a dedicated domain for it, let's say apple.com, and tried to change the Caddy config to:

1. Proxy apple.com to my Nginx VM.
2. Redirect apple.orange.com to apple.com.

and I changed the sites-enabled config for that site on my nginx server to change the server_name to apple.com.

This is where I started running into issues that I did not expect. I started getting too many redirects when I tried to go to apple.com, and found out that apple.com was redirecting to apple.orange.com, which was very weird, and apple.orange.com was redirecting to apple.com as expected, creating a loop.

I changed my Caddyfile to proxy apple.orange.com to my nginx vm and added a site config to serve the same files on orange.apple.com and apple.com, to get the site back up.

Since then, I have been unable to get apple.com to stop redirecting to orange.apple.com.

I tried:

1. Restarting both servers.
2. Removing any mention of apple.orange.com in my Caddyfile, but that just made apple.com redirect to a site that didn't exist anymore.
3. Setting up a completely new instance of Caddy and added just apple.com to proxy to my nginx vm, but I had to copy the certs from my old instance to the new one because I hit LE's rate limit for a week, and that did not make a difference and apple.com was still redirecting to apple.orange.com.
4. Completely removing apple.orange.com from the nginx sites config, but that just made it stop serving the site.
5. Looking into any cache directories that might be holding onto a bad config on either of the webservers, but found nothing.

So here I am, after 3 infuriating days, completely confused by what's happening. Would appreciate any insight on how to go around debugging this.

Here are a bunch of relevant files/configs:

Caddyfile

```
# a bunch of other subdomains exist in the same file, but I also tried with just this.
apple.com, www.apple.com {
  proxy / 10.0.1.108 {
    transparent
  }
}
apple.orange.com
  proxy / 10.0.1.108 {
    transparent
  }
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/apple.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html/apple.com;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name apple.com www.apple.com *.apple.com apple.orange.com;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    autoindex off;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # Compression level (1-9)
    gzip_comp_level     5;

    # Don't compress anything under 256 bytes
    gzip_min_length     256;

    # Compress output of these MIME-types
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-font-opentype
        application/x-font-truetype
        application/x-javascript
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/eot
        font/opentype
        font/otf
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        image/vnd.microsoft.icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/javascript
        text/x-component;

    # Disable gzip for bad browsers
    gzip_disable  "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Obviously apple.com is not mine, and neither is orange.com. Let me know if the actual domains are relevant though (in case it's a DNS issue, which I doubt because the requests are making it to my IP).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was the issue after randomly Googling on migrating a wordpress site to a new domain. Apparently it's not as simple as just pointing the domain to the nginx site, the wordpress installation has a site URL field that [needs to know where the site is served](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).

So the redirects were not coming from Caddy, they were not coming from Nginx, they were coming from the actual wordpress site.